# How to use es6 import instead of require?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export, require

I want to use import in my file, but I cant find the way to replace my require properly

See the code I want to replace

```
const object = {
  first: require('../example/first.json').EXL.PUBLIC,
  second: require('../example/second.json').EXL.PUBLIC,
  third: require('../example/third.json').EXL.PUBLIC
}
```

First question is how can I import those stuff directly to an object? Just like I did with require?

The second one, how can I use import with the `.EXL.PUBLIC` command? To directly import the right branch of the json file?

Comment: What environment are you doing this in? Node.js? What version?

Comment: assuming nodejs ... read [the friendly documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question is how can I import those stuff directly to an object?

You can't, you have to import them and then add them to the objct.

> The second one, how can I use import with the '.EXL.PUBLIC' command?

You have to import the item, then extract that property.

I'm going to assume you're using Node.js:

#### v8 through v11

In an `.mjs` module, you can do it like this:

```
import firstRoot from "../example/first.json";
import secondRoot from "../example/second.json";
import thirdRoot from "../example/third.json";

const object = {
  first: firstRoot.EXL.PUBLIC,
  second: secondRoot.EXL.PUBLIC,
  third: thirdRoot.EXL.PUBLIC
};
```

#### v12

You can still do it as in v11.

If you use ESM with a `.js` file via the new `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, you need to add the `--experimental-json-modules` flag to enable JSON loading. More about v12's support [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/26745), but note that `--type` isn't yet supported (and if it is, will probably be `--entry-type`), and the JSON flag is `--experimental-json-modules`, not `--experimental-json-loader`).